# Testing a Promise using setTimeout with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, jestjs

I'm trying to understand Jest's asynchronous testing.

My module has a function which accepts a boolean and returns a Promise of a value. The executer function calls `setTimeout`, and in the timed out callback the promise resolves or rejects depending on the boolean initially supplied. The code looks like this:

```
const withPromises = (passes) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const act = () => {
    console.log(`in the timout callback, passed ${passes}`)
        if(passes) resolve('something')
        else reject(new Error('nothing'))
    }

    console.log('in the promise definition')

    setTimeout(act, 50)
})

export default { withPromises }
```

I'd like to test this using Jest. I guess that I need to use the mock timers Jest provides, so my test script looks a bit like this:

```
import { withPromises } from './request_something'

jest.useFakeTimers()

describe('using a promise and mock timers', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        jest.runAllTimers()
    })


    test('gets a value, if conditions favor', () => {
        expect.assertions(1)
        return withPromises(true)
            .then(resolved => {
                expect(resolved).toBe('something')
            })
    })
})
```

I get the following error/failed test, whether or not I call `jest.runAllTimers()`

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Can you explain where I'm going wrong and what I might do to get a passing test that the promise resolves as expected?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The call to `jest.useFakeTimers()` mocks every timer function with one that you *must* control. Instead of the timer running automatically, you would advance it manually. The [`jest.runTimersToTime(msToRun)`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html#run-timers-to-time) function would advance it by `msToRun` milliseconds. It's very common that you want to fast-forward until every timer has elapsed and it would be cumbersome to calculate the time it takes for all the timers to finish, so Jest provides [`jest.runAllTimers()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html#run-all-timers), which pretends that enough time has passed.

The problem in your test is that you never call `jest.runAllTimers()` in the test, but you call it in the `afterAll` hook, which is called *after* the tests have finished. During your test the timer remains at zero so your callback is never actually called and Jest aborts it after a predefined interval (default: 5s) to prevent being stuck with a potentially endless test. Only after the test has timed out, you call `jest.runAllTimers()`, at which point it doesn't do anything, since all tests have already finished.

What you need to do is launch the promise and then advance the timer.

```
describe('using a promise and mock timers', () => {
    test('gets a value, if conditions favor', () => {
        expect.assertions(1)
        // Keep a reference to the pending promise.
        const pendingPromise = withPromises(true)
            .then(resolved => {
                expect(resolved).toBe('something')
            })
        // Activate the timer (pretend the specified time has elapsed).
        jest.runAllTimers()
        // Return the promise, so Jest waits for its completion and fails the
        // test when the promise is rejected.
        return pendingPromise
    })
})
```

Comment: This works! Many thanks for the explanation and the explanation and code sample.

Comment: Nice answer! Is is possible to write this test with async / await syntax? 

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a similar problem, where I wanted to fake a async function - that returns a promise - with `setTimeout()`. But I was keep getting a `Exceeded timeout...` error.

I had some issues fixing it in a `async await` syntax. Finally, I solved it by splitting the `const x = await ...` into two lines and putting the `jest.runAllTimers()` between them. (You can also use `jest.advanceTimersByTime()` in the same method).

Here is a full test where I fake a promise with setTimeout:

```
it('test promise with set timeout', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

    const asyncFunction = async () => {
        await sleep(100);
        return true;
    };

    const resultPromise = asyncFunction();

    jest.runAllTimers();

    const result = await resultPromise;

    expect(result).toBe(true);
    jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

PS. If you have multiple tests your probable be better with putting the `useFakeTimers` and `useRealTimers` into a `beforeEach` and `afterEach` blocks.